# set attributes of elements stored in variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway to use jQuery to dynamically set the attributes of HTML elements that are stored in variables?

For example, at one point in my application, a user creates a varying number of select input fields.  For eventual processing by PHP, the elements need to be named in the format `name='input'+siteNumber+'['+x+']'`, where x is the number of elements created in a for loop.

Here's a rough sketch of what I'm thinking needs to be done - THIS IS NOT FUNCTIONAL CODE, IT IS ONLY AN ILLUSTRATION.

```
$(".number_select").change(function(){
    numberFound = $(this).val();
    siteNumber = $(this).parent().attr('data-site_number');
    //HERE'S THE INPUT TO BE NAMED
    selectInput = "<select></select>";

    this['inputArray' + siteNumber] = [];

    for(x = 1; x <= numberFound; x++){  
        //THIS IS WHAT I'D LIKE TO ACCOMPLISH - SETTING THE ATTRIBUTE - THOUGH THIS UNDERSTANDABLY DOES NOT WORK IN THIS PARTICULAR FORMAT           
        this['inputArray' + siteNumber].push(selectInput.attr("name", "species"+siteNumber+"["+x+"]"));
    };

    $(this).parent().append(this['inputArray' + siteNumber]);
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: I consider if you're going to write non functional code you should write a step by  step or pseudocode instead.

Comment: If you create an actual dom element of jquery object you can manipulate the attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone - I actually ended up deciding to handle this a little differently, but it works perfectly - rather than storing the elements in variables, I used a function instead...

```
function inputs(siteNumber, x){
    return ("<select name='selectInput"+siteNumber+"["+x+"]'>"+list+"</select>");
};

$(".number_select").change(function(){
    numberFound = $(this).val();
    siteNumber = $(this).parent().attr('data-site_number');

    this['inputArray' + siteNumber] = [];

    for(x = 1; x <= numberFound; x++){
        this['inputArray' + siteNumber].push(inputs(siteNumber, x));
    };

    $(this).parent().append(this['inputArray' + siteNumber]);
};
```

Don't know why I didn't think of this in the first place, it seems obvious to me now.  Oh well, live and learn.

Answer (score 0):

To vaguely answer your question, you can dynamically generate an element and use jQuery's `attr` for adjusting the name attribute pretty easily like so.

```js
var select = $('<select>').attr('name', 'add-name-here');

$('<option>').attr('value', 'some-value').text('Option').appendTo(select);

$('#wrapper').html(select);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Which outputs

```
<select name="add-name-here">
    <option value="some-value">Option</option>
</select>
```

In your case, instead of adding it to `#wrapper` you would build up the select box as you need and append it to whichever select box has the change? Not sure your specific use case. Hope it helps.